# rails moving layout helpers in it's own module separate from application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, layout, module, helper

My goal is to keep in `application_helper` only the methods that I use in the templates, otherwise my `application_helper` gets too long.

My problem relies in the suffix `Helper`:

**This works**

```
# app/helpers
module ApplicationHelper
  include ApplicationLayout
end

# app/helpers/layouts
module ApplicationLayout
  def my_helper
    puts 'my_helper!'
  end
end
```

**This doesn't**

```
# app/helpers
module ApplicationHelper
  include ApplicationLayoutHelper
end

# app/helpers/layouts
module ApplicationLayoutHelper
  def my_helper
    puts 'my_helper!'
  end
end
```

The error is:

```
Expected app/helpers/layouts/application_layout_helper.rb to define Layouts::ApplicationLayoutHelper
```

So I nest it and I get:

```
Routing Error undefined method `sub' for nil:NilClass
```

Actually I'd like to implement (give your opinion) `app/helpers/layouts/application_helper.rb` but it gives the same error, so for simplicity I stated this case.

Any suggestion on how to extract helper methods for layouts? Is there any convention over configuration I could use?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I tried what you expect and it's pretty straight:

in `helpers/layouts/application_layout_helper.rb`

```
module Layouts
  module ApplicationLayoutHelper
    def my_helper
      'my_helper!' 
    end
  end
end
```

in `helpers/application_helper.rb`

```
module ApplicationHelper
  include Layouts::ApplicationLayoutHelper
end
```

Ad in my view I directly do:

```
<%= my_helper %>
```

I still don't really understand what you'll do with these methods.

Comment: yes, you're right! why have I missed it? - even if methods in the layout module can be accessed in templates I don't really use em there so I like to keep them separated, keeps files smaller, and separate concepts. - thank you

Comment: also thank you for gmaps4rails https://github.com/apneadiving/Gmaps4rails, I'm checking it out!